# Write a java file using JavaPoet in annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations, javapoet

I am trying to use processingEnv.getFiler() to create a source file. But I don't see any source file getting created. Below is the code that I am using:

```
public void javaPoetEg() {
  Filer filer = super.processingEnv.getFiler();
  MethodSpec main = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("testFiler")
    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
    .returns(void.class)
    .addParameter(String[].class, "args")
    .addStatement("$T.out.println($S)", System.class, "Hello, JavaPoet!")
    .build();

  TypeSpec helloWorld = TypeSpec.classBuilder("HelloWorld")
    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
    .addMethod(main)
    .build();


  JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com.ankit.annotation", helloWorld)
    .build();

  try{
    javaFile.writeTo(filer);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

And then calling the function javaPoetEg in the overridden function process() of Annotation processor. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at how `Filer` is supposed to work. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html)
The location of the source files might depends on parameters you specify via command line, or, you have to check the default `generated` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This part: `javaFile.writeTo` writes to a `File`, or a `PrintStream`. So you can do something like this:

```
File file = new File("/target/directory");
javaFile.writeTo(file); // this will make a new File with all the data you added
```

Or:

```
javaFile.writeTo(System.out) // this will print the file representation in the console
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.